# Accessing child of newly created Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Let's say I have a Transaction model, which has an "account" relationship to an Account model.

When creating a new Transaction entry, I assign an account_id field to an already existing Account, but the newly created Transaction does not populate the account relationship.

```
        $tran = new Transaction($arr); //$tran->acount_id = 3
        print_r($tran->account_id); //is 3 (as expected)
        print_r($tran->account); //is empty (should be an Account object)
```

Is there a way to load the Transaction relationships right after it is created? Basically, I would like the print_r() there to show me the contents of the Account_ID=3 entry.

The relationship is defined as below:

```
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Account', 'account_id');
}
```

Comment: is `account_id` "fillable" on the Transaction model?

Comment: yes, account_id is part of **protected $fillable**

Comment: your relationship should be a `belongsTo`

Comment: Hmmm. My Account model has a **belongsTo** relationship to Transaction; I'm pretty confident my Transaction model needs to have a **hasOne** relationship to Account.

Comment: then why are you setting a field named `account_id` on Transaction? this could only work if Transaction belongs to Account ... as Transaction has no 'id' at this point so it would be impossible for an account to have its 'id'

Comment: Logically an Account (model/record) can have many transactions while any Transaction(model/record) belongs to an Account

Comment: @lagbox: my database table **Transactions** has the **account_id** field, because a transaction is associated with an account, and only one account.

Comment: which means Transaction belongs to Account .... the table that has the foreign key on it belongs to the table it references

Comment: @LaurenţiuTerţan Thats exactly the reason why the relation should be **Transaction belongsTo Account** and **Account hasMany Transaction(s)**

Comment: You guys are right :) Thanks